# Changing Toastr position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement the [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

Now I can get alerts and toasts as expected, but I could not apply other options.
It just follows the default option.

I tried the following:

```js
var options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": true,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-center",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
$.simplyToast('This is a success message!', 'success',options);

console.log(options);

console.log($.simplyToast);
```

Now it does not behave as expected, I have set `positionClass` to `BottomCenter`, but I always show right top by default.

How can I change options like mentioned on its [demo page](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html).

Comment: What's `$.simplyToast`? AFAIK, these options are for `toastr`, not for `simplyToast`.

Comment: i downloaded the code from Github and it help note the demo page was this so i am using that code, can u help me with toastr

Comment: SimplyToast, and Toastr are two separate plugins. Refer to [this site](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) for more details about toastr.

Comment: @Rajan Please try like this and check it if its work `toastr.success('We do have the Kapua suite available.', 'Turtle Bay Resort', {positionClass: toast-bottom-center});`

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya i get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: toast is not defined`

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya i have included Toastr.js

Comment: have you check Simple Toast?is working in your js or not?

Comment: Simple Toast was working but i removed that plugin now i am trying Toastr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope Its Work :)
Just try in your code

`toastr.success('We do have the Kapua suite available.', 'Turtle Bay Resort', options);`

Comment: I have included `build/toastr.js` but I get error like this : `Uncaught ReferenceError: toast is not defined`

Comment: Okay So you may check Your .Js as per this link **script.js** [CLick ME](http://plnkr.co/edit/6W9URNyyp2ItO4aUWzBB?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks i think i can figure it now

Comment: if not working properly please set your whole code in [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Okay Happy Codding Bro! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add success as well as error also.

```
set_toastr('', 'This is a success message!', 'success');
```

Its Work you can try this code.